# Cron job gets delayed after sleep

Tags: node.js, macos, cron

I'm pretty new to the whole programming thing, so sorry if the question seems a bit dumb.
My program has multiple cron jobs scheduled to run at specific times of the day on specific weekdays. It's basically an attempt at an automated school schedule.

Whenever my Mac goes to sleep or I close the lid, the program will get delayed by as long as it was closed (if it was asleep 5 min it will be delayed by 5 min). I don't know how cron or launchd really deal with this and I didn't find any other threads about this issue.

This is an example of the code:

```
var mondayTwo = new CronJob('00 59 09 * * 1', function(){
    doAll(la);
}, null, true, 'timezone');
mondayTwo.start();
var tuesdayTwo = new CronJob('00 59 09 * * 2', function(){
    doAll(science);
}, null, true, 'timezone');
tuesdayTwo.start();
var wednesdayTwo = new CronJob('00 59 09 * * 3', function(){
    doAll(la);
}, null, true, 'timezone');
wednesdayTwo.start();
var thursdayTwo= new CronJob('00 59 09 * * 4', function(){
    doAll(la);
}, null, true, 'timezone');
thursdayTwo.start();
var fridayTwo = new CronJob('00 59 09 * * 5', function(){
    doAll(math);
}, null, true, 'timezone');
fridayTwo.start();
```

The program uses node-prompt to get the links, but that works fine, so I don't know what could be causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `launchd` instead of `cron`, tasks that were supposed to have ran while your Mac was sleeping and it will run when it wakes up. There's some more info (including usage) [available here](https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-use-launchd-to-run-services-in-macos-b972ed1e352).

(For what it's worth, Apple recommends using `launchd` instead of `cron`, and may even phase out cron at some point in the future.)

Comment: Ahh thanks. I'll try to look more into launchd and plists, but I have one more question regarding launchd: will I have to make multiple .plist files that execute at different times, or is it possible to make a single .plist with the whole schedule?